# Show Android Statusbar

Tags: android, flutter, statusbar, hidden, status

I'm coding an app with flutter. But for some strange manner the android statusbar is hiding when I open my app. I don't want that. Is there a reason why this is happening?

**This is what I want to achieve:**
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XF5W.png)

**This is what I have:**
[My App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2xpj.png)

Comment: Wrap your page inside SafeArea widget.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick answer. The sad thing is that I already do that:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  _pageTitle,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                ),
              ),
              Center(child: Text(_pageSubTitle)),
              loginForm(context),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But it sadly dosen't work

And I also set the systemvalues in my main function:

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: MAIN_LIGHT_GREEN, // navigation bar color
    statusBarColor: MAIN_LIGHT_GREEN,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show Status Bar :-

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
```

Show tansparent Status Bar :-

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
 ));
```

Comment: This sadly dosen't change anything : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64575975/14535968